# Scrollview with viewpager and listfragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have to make one section in the android app for a mobile site [page](http://www.desidime.com/price-compare/838-nokia-206). . Following are the snaps of the mobile site.

The are two tabs below the product description and at the end there is another view.

[image]

[image][image][image]

Now I was thinking of putting all the content inside a scrollview with a viewpager for the two tabs so that the user can switch between the tab1( Price compare) and tab2 ( Specification).

The viewpager will have listfragments in tab1 and tab2.

But as I researched about it there seems to possible problems with

- Putting a viewpager inside a scrollview
- putting a list inside scrollview.

I m not sure what would be the best way to go about the layout so that the user has the same feel as on the mobile website. Mostly I m looking for a way to make scrolling convenient in these ways
* when the user starts scrolling the listfragment the entire tab and listfragment moves to the top of the screen.

- when the user reaches the bottom of the listfragment the bottom view appears.
- when the user scrolls back up and reached the top of the listview the view on the top(product description) appears.

Thanks for the insights.